# Does Windows limit CPU time?

Tags: c#, windows, performance, cpu-usage, slice

I have written an application in C#, and the first couple of minutes it does more than 11.000 operations (SHA1/AES) per second. But when I let it run for a couple of minutes that drops to 6.000 p/sec, and stays at that level for hours. If I restart the application, it will return to 11.000. CPU usage in Task Manager shows a similar pattern.

Now I'm looking for an explanation, and either there is a huge bug in how I measure the operations/sec (but in that case Task Manager would tell a different story), or Windows gives my program less CPU time once it notices its performing heavy work. Both seem unlikely, so what could be the reason that it runs faster once restarted?

Comment: Your application may not be considered a higher priority, so as more important task arise it knocks yours down possibly. Windows shouldn't care about the work, it only cares about ensuring about it's own functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your time is eventually affected by garbage collection. Are you creating a ton of objects that are not super short lived? If your version of Visual Studio supports it, you should performance profile this scenario and see where your time is being spent by method.

If .NET 4.0+, You can also try using `<gcServer enabled="true" />` in your Web or App config under `<runtime>` node to enable multi-thread garbage collection... Means that it suspends your app temporarily to clean up now and then but it might be better than a continuously consumed thread collecting in the background.

Comment: For each operation an RijndaelManaged object is created, and it should be very shortlived because there are thousands of operations per second. The SHA1 object is static for all workers (im using Parallel ForEach), so shouldnt affect GC. I will review the code to see if I can add .Dipose calls everywhere, because Im new to performance profiling.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach may be part of it, since the TPL has a heuristic that determines how many threads to use based on cores. You can set the affinity mask which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287673/setting-processoraffinity-and-the-tpl

Comment: Don't use/call Dispose if you don't need it - only for unmanaged resources.

Comment: @DavidH - how do you figure out if `IDisposable` class "don't need to be disposed"? Do you dig through implementation of each to make sure there is no unmanaged resources involved? Check all possible derived classes?

Comment: Anything defined as IDisposable should be disposed. I just meant not to try and add Dispose to your own classes. :)